# Postgresql on RDS: how to clean the pg_available_extension_versions view?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have this legacy Postgresql on AWS, running in 12.8. I'm trying to put it up to date, but whenever I try, the preupdate check fails. Logs suck, but I think is due to dangling versions. FWIW, I was able to move almost all the way up on minor versions, and there Postgis was updated automagically, jumping major versions seems to be the issue.

This is the log I have:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------
Upgrade could not be run on Thu Jun 08 11:42:30 2023
------------------------------------------------------------------
The instance could not be upgraded from 12.14.R1 to 13.10.R1 because of following reasons. Please take appropriate action on databases that have usages incompatible with requested major engine version upgrade and try again.
- Following usages in database 'data_mart' need to be corrected before upgrade:
-- The instance could not be upgraded because there are one or more databases with an older version of PostGIS extension or its dependent extensions (address_standardizer, address_standardizer_data_us, postgis_tiger_geocoder, postgis_topology, postgis_raster) installed. Please upgrade all installations of PostGIS and drop its dependent extensions and try again.
- Following usages in database 'dwh' need to be corrected before upgrade:
-- The instance could not be upgraded because there are one or more databases with an older version of PostGIS extension or its dependent extensions (address_standardizer, address_standardizer_data_us, postgis_tiger_geocoder, postgis_topology, postgis_raster) installed. Please upgrade all installations of PostGIS and drop its dependent extensions and try again.
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

Now, I know those are on the right version (and we don't use them all BTW):

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension;

   oid  |    extname   |extowner|extnamespace|extrelocatable|extversion|extconfig|extcondition
 1      |    plpgsql   |  10    |    11      |    false     |  1.0     |         |
 2      |    postgis   |  10    |   16435    |    false     |  3.1.7   |{17224}  |"{...}"
 3      |postgis_raster|   10   |   16435    |    false     |  3.1.7   |         |
```

But I noticed there are some dangling versions on the `pg_available_extension_versions` (all those `2.5.5` and `2.5.5next`):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  pg_available_extension_versions
WHERE
    name
     IN (
     'address_standardizer', 
     'address_standardizer_data_us', 
     'postgis_tiger_geocoder', 
     'postgis_topology', 
     'postgis_raster',
     'postgis'
     )
ORDER BY name, version;


+------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| name                         | version    | installed | superuser | relocatable | schema   | requires                | comment                                                                                                             |
+------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| address_standardizer         | 2.5.5      | false     | true      | true        |          |                         | Used to parse an address into constituent elements. Generally used to support geocoding address normalization step. |
| address_standardizer         | 2.5.5next  | false     | true      | true        |          |                         | Used to parse an address into constituent elements. Generally used to support geocoding address normalization step. |
| address_standardizer         | 3.1.7      | false     | true      | true        |          |                         | Used to parse an address into constituent elements. Generally used to support geocoding address normalization step. |
| address_standardizer         | 3.1.7next  | false     | true      | true        |          |                         | Used to parse an address into constituent elements. Generally used to support geocoding address normalization step. |
| address_standardizer_data_us | 2.5.5      | false     | true      | true        |          |                         | Address Standardizer US dataset example                                                                             |
| address_standardizer_data_us | 2.5.5next  | false     | true      | true        |          |                         | Address Standardizer US dataset example                                                                             |
| address_standardizer_data_us | 3.1.7      | false     | true      | true        |          |                         | Address Standardizer US dataset example                                                                             |
| address_standardizer_data_us | 3.1.7next  | false     | true      | true        |          |                         | Address Standardizer US dataset example                                                                             |
| postgis                      | 2.5.5      | false     | true      | false       |          |                         | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions                                                          |
| postgis                      | 2.5.5next  | false     | true      | false       |          |                         | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions                                                          |
| postgis                      | 3.1.7      | true      | true      | false       |          |                         | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions                                                          |
| postgis                      | 3.1.7next  | false     | true      | false       |          |                         | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions                                                          |
| postgis                      | unpackaged | false     | true      | false       |          |                         | PostGIS geometry and geography spatial types and functions                                                          |
| postgis_raster               | 3.1.7      | true      | true      | false       |          | {postgis}               | PostGIS raster types and functions                                                                                  |
| postgis_raster               | 3.1.7next  | false     | true      | false       |          | {postgis}               | PostGIS raster types and functions                                                                                  |
| postgis_raster               | unpackaged | false     | true      | false       |          | {postgis}               | PostGIS raster types and functions                                                                                  |
| postgis_tiger_geocoder       | 2.5.5      | false     | false     | false       | tiger    | {postgis,fuzzystrmatch} | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder                                                                         |
| postgis_tiger_geocoder       | 2.5.5next  | false     | false     | false       | tiger    | {postgis,fuzzystrmatch} | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder                                                                         |
| postgis_tiger_geocoder       | 3.1.7      | false     | false     | false       | tiger    | {postgis,fuzzystrmatch} | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder                                                                         |
| postgis_tiger_geocoder       | 3.1.7next  | false     | false     | false       | tiger    | {postgis,fuzzystrmatch} | PostGIS tiger geocoder and reverse geocoder                                                                         |
| postgis_topology             | 2.5.5      | false     | true      | false       | topology | {postgis}               | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions                                                                        |
| postgis_topology             | 2.5.5next  | false     | true      | false       | topology | {postgis}               | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions                                                                        |
| postgis_topology             | 3.1.7      | false     | true      | false       | topology | {postgis}               | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions                                                                        |
| postgis_topology             | 3.1.7next  | false     | true      | false       | topology | {postgis}               | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions                                                                        |
| postgis_topology             | unpackaged | false     | true      | false       | topology | {postgis}               | PostGIS topology spatial types and functions                                                                        |
|                              |            |           |           |             |          |                         |                                                                                                                     |
+------------------------------+------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+----------+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So I was trying to delete them from the view, but git another error. Does anyone have an idea?
I'm afraid I can't drop Postgis extension because I'll lose data :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me: I forgot to check a different table for extensions, updated extensions on all tables, and problem solved.